# Good Option for XML Edit/Replace

Tags: c++, xml

I have a *huge* (100k+ lines, 5MB+) XML which acts as a database for my C++ Application. The structure of the XML is quite straight forward, for example, it has chunks of:

```
<foo>
<bar prop="true"/>
<baz>blah</baz>
</foo>
```

The nesting of tags is several levels deep and there are many items with multiple properties. What is a good way to find and replace chunks of this kind of a file? For example, assume that the above section is repeated a few dozen times and in each chunk the value of the tag `<baz>` is different. I'd like to make edits such as:

- Setting all the values contained in tag `<baz>` to a given value.
- Remove chunks containing certain values
- Etc.

So far, I've learnt of the following methods for accomplishing this:

- **Find/Replace**: A no-brainer, trivial solution and also my last fall-back. This approach, IMHO is the most time consuming, error prone and painful method. The absolute last resort.
- **RegExes**: Use regular expressions to match blocks of interest and edit them using replacement expressions. Kinda like this blog entry: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vseditor/archive/2004/08/12/213770.aspx. But I feel this would be error prone and there could be a bunch of missed items if the regex is not exactly right the first time around.
- **Parser & Save**: Whip up a quick program to parse the XML using Xerces or XML DOM Interfaces (or some other XML library), read the XML in, manipulate it as desired and save back to disk. Again, this approach is a slow process, but once its up and running, easy to make modifications and more flexible then RegExes.

Are there any better ways to deal with this? 
(EDIT: Thanks for all the redo it to use a DB suggestions, I know its a huge mess but by "better ways to deal with this" I meant the "find/replace" part. )

Comment: "I have a huge (100k+ lines, 5MB+) XML which acts as a database for my C++ Application" - how not to use XML summed up in one sentence.

Comment: Have you considered using a **database**, as opposed to XML? Because they're explicitly designed for this purpose, things like the above are highly optimized.

Comment: No, don't use regex to edit XML. Never. Ever. Or any other method that disregards the fact that the document is XML.

And yeah, use sqlite or any other real database.

Comment: @CodyGray - that should be an answer as the OP is asking for a better approach -- I'd upvote it :-)

Comment: @Neil, Cody, Cat Plus Plus: It a kinda-legacy app that has been passed onto me (I'm perhaps the 3rd one to inherit it) and needs to be supported as-is (because using a DB will mean the whole app would have to be re-done, so sadly redesigning it is not an option).

Comment: @Bhargav at some point, assuming the application is at all useful, it WILL have to be redone. It's easier to redo it sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Neil: This is basically a weird little tool used to support some not-so-frequently used almost end-of-life products. Its full of hacks and hacked hacks so most likely it will not be reworked. It'll just be pushed till it can go no more.

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat: I'm in a similar position w.r.t. the amount of change allowed. Could you elaborate on how much change you're "allowed" to make?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I'm free to edit the XML as required, but major changes in the structure or redoing it to use a DB etc. is off-limits (since that will cause a change in the code). Currently, I'm looking at writing a simple for-own-use program that will use a SAX parser (using Xerces) to make the changes that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to put the entire document in memory, I would read it using a SAX parser. As you read it, you append the transformed document to a second (or a temp) file. I think it could be pretty fast, and use only a little memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I was thinking of using `SAXParser` in Xerces. Was currently reading http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAXParser.html

Comment: Yes, the DOM approach will probably have issues as I think it needs to hold the whole tree in memory.

Comment: @Adrian: The original C++ app uses the IXMLDOMDocument and other related interfaces. One of my initial ideas was to "re-use" some of this code, but now I'm thinking of against it. `SAXParser` in Xerces seems like a nice option.

Comment: @Bhargav The whole xerces thing is a bit heavyweight, if all you need is a SAX parser. Take a look at Expat at http://expat.sourceforge.net instead - very easy to embed in your code. I used to use Xerces, but switched to Expat with no regrets.

Comment: @Neil: I was just getting started with Xerces. I don't really need to embed the parser into the main app code. I'll be writing a simple own-use-tool that'll help with the XML find/replace and make my life a little easier. I'll give eXpat a try as well, sounds like it'll come in handy elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any better ways to deal with this?

If you must use XML, you could use an XML database such as [BDB XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/xquery-160889.html) (which has C++ APIs). It supports XQuery, transactions, etc.

Other options include [TinyXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/) which I've used with success in the past. Quick and easy to use, not necessarily the fastest on a file of that size, but it will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but even with BDB XML some rework will be needed. I'll consider it for use else where though.

Answer (score 0):

What are your actual memory constraints?  5MB is large but not enormous by current RAM standards.

I would use DOM with XPath if you can, it will be a lot less development work than SAX or other stream-based parsing.  My problem with SAX is that if you are really using this as a in-memory DB, that implies random access on-demand and SAX is not well-suited for that - you will have to parse and reserialize over and over, whereas once you have the DOM at least you can play with it as you like.

Echo comments about to store in-RAM database info too.  Plenty of alternatives that are better suited to this than XML.  Maybe you could implement a tactical solution using DOM/XPath and investigate rip-and-replace as a longer-term project.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers :) There aren't any tight constraints on memory. The app runs on a fairly modern PC: WinXP with 2Gigs of RAM. It uses COM based IXMLDOMDocument to get the work done. I'm not reworking the original app, just writing a simple tool for the find/replace task. In the process I wish to evaluate SAX as an alternative and compare the two, thats my main reason for leaning in favour of SAX.